# How to DM some user using Discord.JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite, sequelize.js, discord.js

I've faced an issue regarding DM'ing a specific user.

This command in my bot basically compares today's date with the date of the assignment and it is supposed to notify the user with this assignment if his deadline is near or has expired. Therefore, I take `useralert` field with user's ID and then transform it into numeric ID  (`useralertID`). On if statement message should be sent to user with this ID when if statement is true.

Following 'Discord.js Guide''s instructions, I defined a user `let user = bot.users.cache.get('useralertID');` and sent a message to this user `user.send('Works!');`.

Unfortunately, instead of messaging a user, it outputs an undefined value or `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined`.

I cannot figure out the issue, so any advice will be really helpful!

Here's the code. Thanks in advance!

```js
var i;
var d = new Date;
var month = d.getMonth() + 1;
var day = d.getDate();
const s = await Tags.count();
if (message.member.hasPermission('KICK_MEMBERS')) {
  for (i = 1; i <= s; i++) {
    const tag = await Tags.findOne({
      where: {
        key: i
      }
    });
    if (tag) {
      var date = tag.get('description');
      let useralert = (tag.get("usernameid")).toString();
      let useralertID = useralert.replace(/[<@>]/g, '');
      let deadday = parseInt(date.slice(0, 2));
      let deadmonth = parseInt(date.slice(3, 5));
      let dayn = deadday - day;
      let monthn = deadmonth - month;
      console.log(dayn.toString() + ' ' + monthn.toString() + ' ' + useralertID);
      if (((dayn <= 2) && (monthn == 0)) || (monthn < 0)) {
        let user = bot.users.cache.get('useralertID');
        user.send('Works!');
        return message.channel.send(`Sent msg to ${user.username}!`);
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[client.users](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=users) its only **cached** users by client. So if you restart bot, this collection will be empty. 
You need send message to your bot or send message to channel where bot can handle this message to be cached in this collection. The you way, if you run this command on guild or if this user are member on your guild you can use `guild.members.cache.get('ID HERE')` or try get guild by id and then in this guild get user by his ID.

### Some example:

```
var i;
var d = new Date;
var month = d.getMonth() + 1;
var day = d.getDate();
const s = await Tags.count();
if (message.member.hasPermission('KICK_MEMBERS')) {

}
    for (i = 1; i <= s; i++) {
        const tag = await Tags.findOne({
            where: {
                key: i
            }
        });
        if (tag) {
            var date = tag.get('description');
            let useralert = (tag.get("usernameid")).toString();
            let useralertID = useralert.replace(/[<@>]/g, '');
            let deadday = parseInt(date.slice(0, 2));
            let deadmonth = parseInt(date.slice(3, 5));
            let dayn = deadday - day;
            let monthn = deadmonth - month;
            console.log(dayn.toString() + ' ' + monthn.toString() + ' ' + useralertID);
            if (((dayn <= 2) && (monthn == 0)) || (monthn < 0)) {
                let user = message.guild.members.cache.get(useralertID);
                if (user) {
                    user.send('Works!').then(() => {
                        return message.channel.send(`Sent msg to ${user.username}!`);
                    }).catch(() => {
                        return message.channel.send(`${user.username} not allow to send DM message!`);
                    })
                } else {
                    return message.channel.send(`the ${useralertID} not guild Member, can\`t send DM to him`);
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, Cipher! Your solution worked perfectly! This issue has really been bugging me for a while and you've solved all my problems, thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs because `user` is not there or is null.
Maybe try `bot.users.cache.get("YOURIDHERE").send("hi")`.
I cannot really help you any further because you did not tell us what you are trying to do.

Comment: Hello! Thanks for the tip. I added some clarifications to my post, hope it will make it more clear. Unfortunately, this does not work either. I still get ```UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined``` error.

Comment: If have not tried using await, this could work: `await bot.users.cache.get("YOURIDHERE").send("hi")` @JoshJohnson

Comment: Yet again, even using await does not help. Still getting the same error message..

Comment: `<Cache>`.get() is not async

Answer (score 0):

Well the issue is that user is undefined like Internal and the error said,

`let user = bot.users.cache.get('useralertID')`

You're using a string here instead of the variable `useralertID`

Regardless you should check if user exists, because you are pulling the id from something indirect, not sure what `Tags` is.

Comment: Thank you for the tip! ```Tags``` was actually my Sqlite table for storing data on users! Anyhow, the issue is resolved!